# Why saving of MSWord document can silently fail?

Tags: python, automation, ms-word, ole

I need to change some custom properties values in many files. Here is an example of code - how I do it for a single file:

```
import win32com.client

MSWord = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
MSWord.Visible = False

doc = MSWord.Documents.Open(file)
doc.CustomDocumentProperties('Some Property').Value = 'Some New Value'
doc.Save()
doc.Close()

MSWord.Quit()
```

Running the same code for `"Excel.Application"` (with minor changes - just to make it work) gives me excellent result. However when I'm using `doc.Save()` or `doc.SaveAs(same_file)` for MSWord it silently fails. I don't know why, but changes are not saved.

Now my workaround is to use `SaveAs` to a different file, it also works good. But I want to understand why I have such strange behaviour for MSWord files and how it can be fixed?

**Edit**: I changed my code, not to misdirect people with silent fail cause of try/except.
However, thanks to all of them for finding that defect in my code :)

Comment: is that your actual code now?

Comment: Yeah it is, and I think I'm using everything right. Howevere it doesn't work on my machine, and I can't understand why - that's why I'm asking about it. May be someone have had same problem...

Comment: I managed to reproduce your results, but have no idea how to fix them.  I'm seconding this question...WTF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using the `CustomDocumentProperties` in the wrong way, and as other people pointed out, you could not see it, because you were swallowing the exception.

Moreover - and here I could not find anything in the documentation - the `Saved` property was not reset while changing properties, and for this reason the file was not changed.

This is the correct code:

```
msoPropertyTypeBoolean = 0
msoPropertyTypeDate = 1
msoPropertyTypeFloat = 2
msoPropertyTypeNumber = 3
msoPropertyTypeString = 4

import win32com.client

MSWord = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
MSWord.Visible = False

doc = MSWord.Documents.Open(file)
csp = doc.CustomDocumentProperties
csp.Add('Some Property', False, msoPropertyTypeString, 'Some New Value')
doc.Saved = False
doc.Save()
doc.Close()

MSWord.Quit()
```

Note: there is no error handling, and it is definitely not of production quality, but it should be enough for you to implement your functionality.
Finally, I am guessing the values of the property types (and for the string type the guess is correct) but for the others there could be some issue.

Comment: It really wasn't a production quality, but we are not going to product it at all. Just our Share Point site gone crazy, and now we need to fix a few hundreds of files. Nobody want to do it manually :) Really switching Saved property to False manually helped to solve my problem! Many Thanks! I just was confused cause Excel resets Saved flag automatically.

Answer (score 1):

you're saving file only if `Value` was successfully changed. May be you could try to remove `try`-`except` clause and see what is actually happening when you're file is not saved. And, btw, using bare `except` is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

> (a) Check to see if you have file write access
>
> (b) Make sure you code catches using the COMException
>
> (C) are you gracefully terminating excel/words when creating multiple documents

**Darknight**

Answer (score 0):

It fails silently since you ignore errors (`except: pass`).

The most common reason why saving a Word file usually fails is that it's open in Word.